# How to forecast course completion percentage?

Tags: logistic, model, binary-data

The goal of this task is to be able predict percentage of students who registered a specified term which in the future will pass the course.

I did a logistic regression for binary response whether the student was approved the same semester or not. Interesting variables were which program they went, age of the individual, previous studies, if the student began to read in the fall or spring

But right now I'm a little unsure how to take me on. 
Feeling a little confused as to how I can predict percentage of students who registered a specified term which in the future will pass the course?

Comment: Build a model where binary response is whether student completed the course or not. Build this model using the data of previous years. Plug-in this years data. Calculate the percentage.

Comment: Should I still use a logistic regression? and how am I supposed to plug-in data? Should I then check if the students from this year are approved or not? @mpiktas